# Checking for existence of a record in sql databse returns wrong results

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm working on my project in Asp.net (C#), I have one textbox to get a string from the user (by button click), And like all the strings that i get from the user - (username, email, etc), I check if the input string is exists in the database (SQL), if it exists, an error message is shown.

I use this code in .cs Code behind file:

```
string cn = cnTextBox.Value;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [CN] FROM [dbo].[MyTable] WHERE CN=@CN");   
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CN", cn);
cmd.Connection = con;
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
bool theSame = false;
if (dr.HasRows())
    while (dr.Read())
    {            
        string value = dr["CN"].ToString();
        if (cn == value)
            theSame = true;
    }

if (theSame)
    errorMessage.Style["display"] = "block";
else
    errorMessage.Style["display"] = "none";
if (!theSame)
    // code to insert the string to a new record in the database, works fine.
```

As you can see i use `WHERE` clause inside a `SELECT` (parameterized) query, in order to verify if the string is already exists in the database.

Note: The "CN" column in the database is of type `varchar(50)`.

The problem is, (never hppened before, and it is really not the first time i do that), if i have the string "xxxxx" in a record in the database (in the column CN) and the input string that i want to insert is "xxxxx**n**" (not the same length) or "xxxxn" (not the same chars), the above check returns that this input is already exists in the database and the error message is shown. And even more strange? the string is inserted to the database after all.

**Note: It happens over and over again when i test my project using Internet Explorer 11, but never happened when i used another bowser like Firefox.**

Is something wrong? Any suggestions?

Thanks for help!

Comment: What are cn and value if you insert break point to if(cn == value) statement?

Comment: The way you're describing the problem suggests you need to do more research: narrow down the problem further by testing your code in isolation (browser should not matter), verify what is actually passed in (using logging or the debugger), ...

Comment: Btw, **the string is inserted to the database after all.** . If it shouldn't be inserted, you should use unique index as a second level business logic protection.

Comment: You are writing a lot of unnecessary code. If the execution of your command returns rows then you don't need to check the values returned. They are the same. Moreover you can use  IF EXISTS to shorten your code to a simple ExecuteScalar

Comment: @Berkay, I inserted a break point and saw that both value and cn have the same content, but i can now understand it according what Steve said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment. Are you sure you are looking at the same database that you application is using?

Unrelated tips:

1. `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable` so each should be in a `using` block.
2. You may want to [stop using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).
3. You can pass the connection to the constructor of the `SqlCommand`.
4. Rather than `dr["CN"].ToString();` prefer `dr.GetString(0);`
5. SQL string comparisons are case insensitive by default. C# string equality are case sensitive. SQL might find the record and your C# code could dismiss it as being different.
6. Any question including the phrase "*[doing X]* returns wrong results" misses the point that computers do exactly what you ask them to, so unless this is a freakish bug which millions of other users have not seen over decades of usage; then you need to realise it is returning the *right* results for what it has been asked. This shift in perception, along with use of the debugger is likely to help you diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

trim your value been passed. may be extra space gets added that make it differ like you said 'xxxx' and 'xxxxn', n may be extra space.